Need help handling testing of Twilio Flex application that has single signon enabled
I have a flex application that is using Single Signon.  We are looking at doing some automated testing of our application and need to be able to have the CypressIO test login.
We are running into issues in that we get redirected to SSO, which our organization has setup with two-factor authentication.
We could potentially login through the console first, but we also have two factor there on our account.
What are the recommended ways to handle flex application login for test purposes.

Ideally, you should always first log in to the authentication platform, and only after being logged in, access Flex. Once the authentication in CypressIO is completed, you will not have any issues with 2FA.
Additionally, if you have admin access to the Twilio console, you can log in to Flex directly through the Twilio console, without using SSO.
